# Passing 2 string from one PHP file to the other using CURL

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

My first.php file

```
$statusString = "u=10000;t1=1479409;s=10;r=-33;v=3.68;";
$macaddress= "10000";
$url = 'second.php';
$fields = array(
    'newFormat'=>urlencode($statusString),
    'MACAddress'=>urlencode($macaddress)
   );
$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
{ 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string,'&');
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch);
```

Here I am trying to send data from my first.php to my second.php

My second.php file

```
if (isset($_GET['newFormat']))
{ 
    $str = $_GET['newFormat'];
}
else 
    $str = 'no data';
if (isset($_GET['MACAddress']))
{ 
    $macAddress = $_GET['MACAddress'];
}
```

Here I am trying to retrieve the data sent by first.php.

My first.php invokes second.php, but second.php cannot retrieve any data. In my second.php, $str turn out to be 'no data' as in the the else part and $macAddress is empty! Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: Your `rtrim` usage is incorrect you need to assign it to the variable. `first.php` should be opening `second.php` then whatever `second.php` does should occur.

Comment: @chris85 So it should be `fields = rtrim($fields_string,'&');` ?

Comment: `$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');`

Comment: @chris85 It is still not passing data

Comment: What happens on page2? Nothing occurs in the code you've posted.

Comment: It uses the data received, forms  a topic and published on a mqtt broker. The second.php is tried and tested. So I know it works well. Only issue is passing the data from first.php to second.php

Comment: Does the request from first make it to second?

Comment: Got the problem. In my second.php, I should be using `_POST` and not `_GET`

Answer (score 0):

In second.php, should be using _POST and not _GET